# How do I do a partial match on an IN statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am joining multiple tables into a single query. I need to do a partial match on values in an IN statement. Here is an example.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    am.id AS id, 
    am.flagged AS flagged, 
    am.name AS name, 
    am.type AS type, 
    am.file AS file, 
    am.s3_tag AS s3_tag, 
    am.low_s3_tag AS low_s3_tag 
FROM accounts_media am 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_location_media alm ON am.id = alm.media_id 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_location al ON al.id = alm.location_id 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_person_media apm ON am.id = apm.media_id 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_person ap ON ap.id = apm.person_id 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_event_media_record aemr ON am.id=aemr.media_id 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_medianote_media_record amma ON am.id=amma.media_id 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_medianote amn ON amma.medianote_id=amn.id 
WHERE 
    am.account_id = '1234' 
    AND am.flagged = FALSE 
    AND ('Da' IN (SELECT first_name FROM accounts_person WHERE account_id = '1234') 
    AND ('Rob' IN (SELECT first_name FROM accounts_person WHERE account_id = '1234')
```

In the

`AND ('Da' IN (SELECT first_name FROM accounts_person WHERE account_id = '1234')`

statement there are values that say 'Dan', 'Daniel', etc. in the table. There is also 'Rob' and 'Robert'. I need that statement to make sure and name that contains 'Da' AND any name that contains 'Rob' from that table. Is there a way to do this?

So a record can be linked to multiple people in the accounts_person table. So lets say I have three records.

Record One: A person named Dan is attached to the record.

Record Two: A person named Robert is attached to the record.

Record Three: A person named Dan and a person named Robert are attached to the record.

I want the query to only return Record Three because it has the match of 'Da' and 'Rob'.

Comment: Are you looking for records where the name starts with Da and Rob, or any records that start with Da or Rob?

Comment: I need records that have Da AND Rob. Not necessarily start with but contains.

Comment: Seems like you should be using a `JOIN`.

Comment: njk, can you give an example of how I would use a `JOIN` to do this?

Comment: How are you attaching Dan and Robert to the record?  does this mean that there are two accounts_person records attached to a single account_id?

Comment: I have the accounts_media table that contains the list of records. Then there is the accounts_person table that contains a list of people. The list of people have a join table with the accounts_media table. Then then each record is linked to an account. So I am pretty much doing a search for records in a certain account that contain people that match 'Da' AND 'Rob'. This is a little complicated but it would really help to do it in SQL instead of iterate through all records with code.

Comment: So, you are looking for accountIds with 2 or more accounts_persons meeting the matching critera and then seeing all the records attached to those people, including duplicate records?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE 
    am.account_id = '1234' 
    AND am.flagged = FALSE 
    -- AND ( ap.first_name LIKE '%Da%' OR ap.first_name LIKE '%Rob%')
    AND EXISTS 
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM accounts_person apx
           WHERE apx.first_name LIKE '%Da%'
             AND apx.account_id = am.account_id
        )
    AND EXISTS 
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM accounts_person apy
           WHERE apy.first_name LIKE '%Rob%'
             AND apy.account_id = am.account_id
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think you want a like statement, with a wild card after the Da.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    am.id AS id, 
    am.flagged AS flagged, 
    am.name AS name, 
    am.type AS type, 
    am.file AS file, 
    am.s3_tag AS s3_tag, 
    am.low_s3_tag AS low_s3_tag 
FROM accounts_media am 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_location_media alm ON am.id = alm.media_id 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_location al ON al.id = alm.location_id 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_person_media apm ON am.id = apm.media_id 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_person ap ON ap.id = apm.person_id 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_event_media_record aemr ON am.id=aemr.media_id 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_medianote_media_record amma ON am.id=amma.media_id 
    LEFT JOIN accounts_medianote amn ON amma.medianote_id=amn.id 
WHERE 
    am.account_id = '1234' 
    AND am.flagged = FALSE 
    AND (accounts_person.first_name like '%Da%'
    OR accounts_person.first_name like '%Rob%') 
    AND accounts_person.account_id = '1234'
```

Comment: The only problem with that is if I need to make sure that two or more first names in the accounts_person table. I have edited the question above to reflect this.

Comment: Your update still doesn't work because accounts_person.first_name will never be LIKE '%Da%' AND LIKE '%Rob%' because a single record will only have one at a time. So the AND there will always fail. That's why I need to do an IN statement with a nested SELECT statement. Does that make sense?

Comment: The OR there doesn't work either. Because then it will give me results that may contain only 'Da' or only 'Rob' and not records that have both.

Comment: It might be helpful to give some data that you would like to have returned

Comment: I updated the original question with an example at the bottom. Does that help?